# The use of quotation marks when loading a package in R

Tags: r, r-package

Is there any reason to prefer the use of quotation marks when loading a package; e.g.

```
library("MASS")
```

over loading packages without putting the name in quotes;

```
library(MASS)
```

Looking back at some old code, I seem to switch between the two with no noticeable consequences. Is there a best practise recommendation to follow?

Comment: [Recommended reading](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#nse-downsides)

Comment: In addition, if you search the source code of `library()`, you can find this snippet:  `if (!character.only) package <- as.character(substitute(package))`.  So no matter if you use `library("MASS")` or `library(MASS)` because you didn't change the default argument `character.only = FALSE`, it would convert the package variable to a character type, i.e. they are not different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an example of non-standard evaluation. I'm not sure there is "best practice" regarding whether you should put packages in quotes. But

- If you submit a paper to the [Journal of Statistical Software](https://www.jstatsoft.org/) they insist that package names are in quotes
- [Advanced R programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#nse-downsides) gives the downsides and also suggests against it.

The argument against

```
library(MASS)
```

is that for new users, it's hard to guess what

```
pkg = "MASS"
library(pkg)
```

will do.